# What is "JVAL:kolrcrfc durid = 10" and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: sqlplus, oracle12c

I am trying to get all the info I would need to create a copy of a user. I found this great query:

```
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('USER', USERNAME) ||'/' DDL
 FROM DBA_USERS where username = 'TEST_COPY_USER';
```

It works great, but when I put this in my script the file I create looks like this:

```
JVAL:kolrcrfc durid = 10

CREATE USER "TEST_COPY_USER" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'ENCRYPTED PASSWORD'
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE "TESTADMIN01"
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"/
```

What is this "JVAL:kolrcrfc durid = 10" and how do I get rid of it? I cannot find a reference to it anywhere. Note: It also shows up when I manually run the query inside sqlplus.

Comment: It looks like the Temporary LOB reference count is turned on. Can you please try setting this event and try your query: `alter session set events '32761 trace name context forever, level 1';`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but no go. I still get the JVAL line in my results.

Comment: May i know which Oracle Database version being used at your end?

Comment: Currently running 12.1